# How do I get the man page for a sub command using vim?

Tags: vim, man, vi

For example, I get the manpage for a command using 'K':

```
docker run
+------------ cursor is on d
# if I press 'ESC-SHIFT-K', I'll get a manpage for docker
```

Now, if I want to get the manpage for `docker run`, which is a valid shell command (`$ man docker run`):

```
docker run
-------+---- cursor is on r
# no man pages avail for command: run
```

---

How do I use Caps-K in `vim` to access a man page for a combo command?

Comment: One possible approach is using `docker-run` (and works by selecting the word pressing `V` or `Ctrl+V`).